# Show form field and tree view together odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I managed to add two custom fields to the settings by inheriting **res.config.settings** in a new module created. The xml page of the same is

```
<record id="op_product_fast_moving_parts_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">Configure Fast Moving Parts</field>
        <field name="model">fastmovingparts.config.settings</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="FastMoving">
                <header>
                    <button string="Apply" type="object" name="execute" class="oe_highlight"/>
                    or
                    <button string="Cancel" type="object" name="cancel" class="oe_link"/>
                </header>

                <separator string="Configure Fast Moving Parts"/>

                <group name="Configure Fast Moving Parts">
                    <field string="Minimum Quantity" name="fast_moving_parts_min_qty"/>
                </group>
                <group>
                    <field string="Interval" name="fast_moving_parts_chk_interval"/>
                </group>

            </form>                

        </field>
    </record>
```

It is updating the settings when clicking on the **Apply** button.

Here I have one more requirement that I need to open a wizard on clicking Apply button which will display products tree. How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get your question, but I think that you want to open a wizard on clicking Apply button which will display products tree.

Comment: Sorry for the vagueness, I have updated the question.

Comment: I've not time now to help you so look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29442703/odoo-8-openerp-setting-values-using-wizard-from-list-view) it will help you